# Why the difference between definitions of the discrete/continuous Fourier transforms?

Tags: fourier-analysis

I should preface this question with the fact that I'm not familiar with the meaning/utility of the Fourier transform. Perhaps more accurately: I may have learned them, but have since forgotten; in any case, I'm just looking into some info about it to help a student out with its calculation, as I figured that would be easy enough. The [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#Definition) page on the Discrete Fourier transform defines the transform as
$$X_k=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}x_n\exp\left(-\frac{2\pi i nk}{N}\right)$$
for a sequence $\{x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_{N-1}\}$, with $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Given the sequence $\{1,0,1,-1\}$, I have
$$\begin{align*}
X_k&=\sum_{n=0}^3x_n\exp\left(-\frac{2\pi ink}{4}\right)\\[1ex]
&=\underbrace{1}_{n=0}+\underbrace{\exp\left(-\pi ik\right)}_{n=2}-\underbrace{\exp\left(-\frac{3\pi ik}{2}\right)}_{n=3}\\[1ex]
&=1+\left(e^{-i\pi}\right)^k-\left(e^{-3i\pi/2}\right)^k\\[1ex]
&=1+(-1)^k-i^k
\end{align*}$$
I then have $X_k=\{1,-i,3,i\}$, where $k\in\{0,1,2,3\}$. However, checking with Mathematica, I should be getting $\dfrac{1}{2}\left\{1,i,3,-i\right\}$. As it turns out, there's a slight modification in the definition that accounts for the difference in our results. (`Fourier` is defined with $\frac{1}{\sqrt n}$ multiplied by a sum containing a *positive* exponent.)

Now, the factor of $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt n}$, I can wrap my mind around (sort of): in the article about the continuous transform, [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierTransform.html) mentions that the use of $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ as opposed to $\dfrac{1}{2\pi}$ is a way of "restoring symmetry". **But why the sign change in the exponent?** The same disparity can be seen in [the Mathematica documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FourierTransform.html) and [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Definition). **Does using one sign over the other confer any special advantage?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's back up a tad and talk about Fourier series.

Call $\phi_k(t) = \exp(ikt)$. Let's work on $L^2[0,2\pi]$. We can take the Fourier expansion of some function:

$$
x = \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} a_k \phi_k
$$

where

$$
a_k = \frac{\langle f, \phi_k \rangle}{\langle \phi_k, \phi_k \rangle} = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} x(t) \phi_k(t)^*dt = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} x(t)\exp(-ikt)dx
$$

Notice that we could've just as easily called $\phi_k(t) = \exp(-ikt)$ and expanded. The $a_k$ in this case would be the conjugate of the above. So this choice is somewhat arbitrary. Keep that in mind.

---

How does this fit in with the DFT? Let's suppose you wanted to approximate the $a_k$ of the Fourier expansion of $x$. This is just the approximation of an integral. Let's do that in the simplest way imaginable — the left rectangle rule.

We'll take a uniform grid on $[0,2\pi]$ using $t_n = \Delta t \cdot n = \frac{2\pi}{N} \cdot n$, so that:

$$
a_k \approx \frac{1}{2\pi} \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}x(t_n)\exp(-ikt_n) \Delta t = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{k=0}^{N-1}x\left(2 \pi n / N\right)\exp\left(-i 2 \pi k  n / N\right)
$$

Now just define $x_n := x(2\pi n /N)$, and you see that $X_k \approx a_k$. If you approximate $N$ of the $a_k$ with $X_k$, you now have an $N \times N$ linear system which can be represented by a matrix (try writing it out!). This is non-normalized [DFT matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFT_matrix). If you want this matrix to be ortho*normal*, you need to change the factor of $\frac{1}{N}$ to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}$.

Also if you look back to where I mentioned expanding in the conjugate of the $\phi_k$, you hopefully you realize that doing this derivation under this basis would result in the sign flip in the exponent.

So in a nutshell, mostly these things you ask about are just design choices.

Comment: So does the arbitrariness of selecting a negative vs a positive exponent have something to do with the property that $\langle x,y\rangle=\overline{\langle y,x\rangle}$?

Comment: It's two things: the first I mentioned in the answer, i.e. expanding $x(t)$ in the basis $\{ e^{int} \}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ versus  $\{ e^{-int} \}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$. If you expand in the second basis, the coefficients *in this expansion* are the conjugate of the coefficients of the *first* expansion, yea? Secondly, in both cases, $a_k^* = a_{-k}$, so everything is there no matter which you choose.